# Select Combobox with Selenium IDE

Tags: combobox, selenium-ide

In my application I have lot of combo boxes available. I need to click an arrow button which is on combo box. I am using Selenium IDE. When I record the clicking of the arrow button from combo box it will work at that time, but when I come back to same page it will display that the element is not found.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you locate the combo box element in Selenium?

Comment: using select button which is available in selenium ide.

Comment: Please can you paste your selenium code and the page HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you to understand first, how values are coming into your combo boxes. I think when you clicked on combo box, AJAX call will be fired and values will be loaded into your combo boxes.

You can use the command "**waitForElementPresent**" or "**waitForTextPresent**" when clicked on combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Do not click on *combo box* button while recording.......

Do **right click** on button and get element by **ID**